# Pinterest style columns in one pass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array of images and I'd like to iterate against it once to display 3 columns. Ideally I'd like to have a Bootstrap col-xs-4 style on each element so that the column wraps to the next column or the next row ... but this approach doesn't work correctly.

If I have 5 images of different heights, the first 3 work out perfectly ... at image 4 I have a vertical spacing issue. You can see this what I mean at this [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/f3buuw3q/) -

Can I correct this? If I re-construct my array into 3, I can place each images within a col-xs-4 group, column by column, and there are no vertical spaces, but this is inefficient.

In other words ...

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-4">
//for-loop here
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
//for-loop here
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
//for-loop here
</div>

</div> <!-- row -->
```

The above works fine, but again, is inefficient as I have to slice my array ... a lot. I'm trying to optimize code to not have to do this.

Comment: you can simply use CSS columns if linear ordering is not an important part  of the display. that's why pinterest works: no dates means that css-ordered columns are not disorienting like they would be for stack, or other time-heavy listings. might look into isotope.js too.

Comment: Linear ordering is the most important part of the display. Otherwise, this is trivial to implement.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out [_CSS Columns_](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/)? Other than that, you need to use JavaScript. For doing that with larger amounts of data, libraries such as Masonry were written.